# obtain user location and show on angular-map

Tags: angular, location, angular-google-maps

I want to use google map on my angular 4 application.how can I obtain users location and show on map also detect address when users changed their location

Comment: I visit this link : https://angular-maps.com/
but I cant find my answer

Comment: There are few more packages available in NPM. please check as well.

Comment: I checked them before.many of them refer to this link

Comment: Are you getting google map in your application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating Google Maps to get Current Location in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602800/integrating-google-maps-to-get-current-location-in-angular-2)

Comment: yes, I have it and works but just shows the map,
see this link please : http://primer.nyasha.me/maps/google
my project is like this

Comment: my problem is different

Comment: Solved with this code 


 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
        })